# Get multiple Data from web service using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, xml, web-services, asp.net-ajax

I have a web service function that returns dataTable... I want to add data from this table1 tags...

```
  <Table1 diffgr:id="Table11" msdata:rowOrder="0">
    <ProductID>1</ProductID><ProductName>A</ProductName><AvailableProduct>8</AvailableProduct>
    </Table1>
<Table1 diffgr:id="Table12" msdata:rowOrder="1">
    <ProductID>2</ProductID><ProductName>B</ProductName><AvailableProduct>3</AvailableProduct>
    </Table1>
<Table1 diffgr:id="Table13" msdata:rowOrder="2">
    <ProductID>3</ProductID><ProductName>C</ProductName><AvailableProduct>7</AvailableProduct>
    </Table1>
<Table1 diffgr:id="Table14" msdata:rowOrder="3">
    <ProductID>4</ProductID><ProductName>D</ProductName><AvailableProduct>0</AvailableProduct>
    </Table1>
<Table1 diffgr:id="Table15" msdata:rowOrder="4">
    <ProductID>5</ProductID><ProductName>E</ProductName><AvailableProduct>3</AvailableProduct>
    </Table1>
<Table1 diffgr:id="Table16" msdata:rowOrder="5">
    <ProductID>6</ProductID><ProductName>F</ProductName><AvailableProduct>1</AvailableProduct>
    </Table1>
```

and here is my Jquery Code... this won't append anything to the table how can I solve this

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Btn").click(function () {
            alert();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'WebserviceDS.asmx/GetTable',
                dataType: 'xml',
                data:"{}",
                Success: function (xml) {
                    $(xml).find('Table1').each(function () {
                        $("<tr><td>" + $(xml).find('ProductID').text() + "</td>").appendTo("table");
                        alert($(xml).find('ProductID').text());
                        $("<td>" + $(xml).find('ProductName').text() + "</td>").appendTo("table");
                        $("<td>" + $(xml).find('AvailableProduct').text() + "</td></tr>").appendTo("table");
                    })
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert(err);
                }

            });
            return false;
        })
    })
```

in these alerts, it won't show anything ..this is my HTML code

```
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <button id="Btn">Click Me</button>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>ProductID</th>
                    <th>ProductName</th>
                    <th>AvailableProduct</th>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: But the alerts get executed?

Comment: Can you share exact output of `xml` in the `success` callback method? Also not it should be `success` note `Success` (Assuming) TYPO while posting question

Comment: @Satpal sorry now i executed  my last code  i have "123456"  in alert 0_o

Comment: @Satpal then i have this in result 
ProductID ProductName AvailableProduct
123456
123456
123456
123456
123456
123456
ABCDEF 837031 ABCDEF 837031 ABCDEF 837031 ABCDEF 837031 ABCDEF 837031 ABCDEF 837031

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/#jQuery-each-array-callback) use call back `value` to access object at index.
2. Create complete `<TR>` then append requisite `<TD>` child elements then finally append `<TR>` to Table.

*Example*

```
$(xml)
    .find('Table1')
    .each(function (index, value) {
        var tr = $('<tr>');
        tr.append($('<td>').text($(value).find('ProductID').text()));
        tr.append($('<td>').text($(value).find('ProductName').text()));
        tr.append($('<td>').text($(value).find('AvailableProduct').text()));
        tr.appendTo("table");
    });
```

Comment: @Setpal Thank you very Much